# How to tell if a Android IAP/Subscription has been refunded?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-developer-api

I am integrating with the Google Play Developer API for IAP. How can my server know if the subscription/product has been refunded? All I can tell is its cancelled. I am looking at `https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions#resource` but cannot find information on whether something is refunded and isit partial/full.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [SUBSCRIPTION_REVOKED](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications#scale_notification_processing) RTDN, it also shifts the expire date in validation response when the purchase is refunded/revoked